# Sharepoint forum

Tags: untagged

My company is looking for a good forum to use with Sharepoint? Are there any good free forums?

Sharepoint version is MOSS 2007. Discussion lists are not acceptable.

Comment: At the very least, you should probaby include your sharepoint version.  Possibly some detail about what you want/need/expect the forum to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lightening Forums](http://www.lightningtools.com/lightning-storm-forums-for-sharepoint/default.aspx) are not free and not nearly as feature rich as Community Server, but are another option

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Telligent's Community Server Evolution, which integrates with SharePoint and does discussion forums/blogs/wikis very well.

http://communityserver.com/news/team-blog/community-server-evolution/
http://communityserver.com/products/evolution/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, do you mean you're looking for a place to ask questions or a plug in to improve the forums aspect of MOSS 2007?

If the latter, the community server people [talk a good game](http://communityserver.com/products/evolution/) about sharepoint integration for their forum/CMS product, and it isn't a bad blog & forum platform to be honest, though I haven't personally tried integrating it with anything.

You can turn off the bits you don't want so you can switch off all but the forum functionality, or you can add to it with plugins if you want to add something new or tweak whatever is there already.

It isn't free, but IIRC you do get access to the source code and they are quite helpful when you have problems, so I'd regard it as a reasonable investment. Microsoft themselves use Community Server quite a lot, if you know what to look for you'll see it crop up quite a lot where they need forum OR blogging tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Community Kit for SharePoint](http://cks.codeplex.com/), it is open source and may give you what you require.

Comment: Not a completed project and not much functionality yet.

Answer (score 0):

Quest provides a free enhancement to the built in discussion boards.

A video demonstrating the web part in action

http://www.screencast.com/users/CurtisKelly/folders/Jing/media/4eaded83-b60e-4226-88ea-bd9018d9c30f

Links to the 32 and 64 bit versions of the web part.

http://sharepointforall.com/media/p/320.aspx

http://sharepointforall.com/media/p/321.aspx

Comment: Do you have a link for actual enhancement?